# @RenderBody for javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there such a way to emulate `@RenderBody()` in javascript or javascript library? I am attempting to start a new html/javascript project (no server-side language) and was hoping to be able to emulate the functionality of the `@RenderBody()` feature in razor.

For clarification, in .NET MVC projects, you can have a `_Layout.cshtml` file that contains a "template" for your page; css/javascript includes, etc.

```
<!-- include javascript and css -->
...
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
....
```

The content of your page would live in a file such as `index.cshtml`, which would render at `@RenderBody()`. Can I achieve something similar purely on the client side or does there need to be some sort of server-side language for this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: The question is a little vague. Do you mean you want to render the results from your endpoint in your current Razor layout file but from the client and not the server?

Comment: I am looking for a solution that will emulate the functionality of @RenderBody() but in an html/javascript project. No server side language. Will edit question

Comment: You are much better off re-thinking your approach.  Google for "SPA" - Single Page Application.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I was considering that approach, since it is basically what I was looking for. I was hoping for feel of multiple pages with one common "template" similar to the `@RenderBody()` feature mentioned above.

Comment: It is far, far, far, far simpler to simply set up one page with the features/pages/views you need and show/hide rather than trying to actually *render* as needed.  If you really want to use the render approach, go with Durandal, which has that functionality built in.  Coding from scratch will be a ... job.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are looking for is `@RenderSection()`

Like `@RenderBody()`, `@RenderSection()` can render code from a view in a specific location on your master page

Include this is your master page where you'd like the code to be placed

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

And this in your page that's being called

```
// your page content

@section scripts{
    //your javascript code here
}
```

//Update// This is a server-side solution that you can use if it comes to that

Comment: I am looking for a solution purely in html/js. I've modified the question to hopefully be more clear. Thanks for the try

Comment: Yeah I just caught the tail end of that question after I posted... the thing about `@RenderBody` is that is it back-end so it is loaded onto the server before the client views the page. JavaScript is a client-side script, so running JavaScript before the page reaches the client is just not possible.

Comment: Also, reading from a file is a server-side problem. JavaScript can only handle client-side code, so no, reading from a file and outputting with JavaScript onto a part of your page is not possible as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking after a client-side MVC (or MVVM) framework such as [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/), [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) or [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/).

You can have a look at [this article on Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/27/journey-through-the-javascript-mvc-jungle/) as a starting point.